# Scala: ArrayBuffer doesn't take parameters

Tags: arrays, scala, types, type-conversion

I have a variable of a trait that accepts multiple datatypes `{Int, Long, String, Double}`.

I need to do some math operation on this variable. So I try to convert the variable to an `ArrayBuffer [Any]`.

```
def toArray (x: MultiV): ArrayBuffer [Any] = {
    val a = new ArrayBuffer[Any]()
    for (i <- 0 until rows) a += x(i)   // x(i) belongs to set {Int, Long, String, Double}
    a
}
```

Now as I need to perform some operations on this try to convert ArrayBuffer to their individual types.

```
def printInd (a: ArrayBuffer [Any], b: Seq[Int]) = {
    val v = a(0) match {
        case _: Double   => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [Double]]
        case _: Int      => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [Int]]
        case _: Long     => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [Long]]
        case _: String   => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [String]]
        case _  =>  println ("printInd: type not supported")
    }
    for (i <- b) print(v(i) + " ")  // Error: Any does not take parameters
}
```

I get an error on the print statement saying

```
Any does not take parameters    
print(v(i))  
      ^
```

`v` is of class ArrayBuffer so I am assuming it should take an integer parameter to return the element at that index. (Also I assume, if `a(0)` is `Int`, `v` is `ArrayBuffer [Int]`. Or is it still `ArrayBuffer [Any]`?).
Can anyone please explain what I am understanding wrong.

Comment: I updated the code. I was thinking the match statement will assign `a.asInstanceOf[...]` to `val v`.

Comment: If you discard type information, you are likely to spend a lot of your time arguing with the Scala type checker.  Perhaps `MultiV` should be a generic type.  It looks like the values you extract into the buffer will all be of the same type (all `Double` or all `Int` etc.).  Can you make that an explicit type parameter?

Comment: Compare the title and the error message in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `println` statement returns a `Unit`. Thus, the type of `v` is inferred to be as a lower bound of `ArrayBuffer[Int]` and `Unit`, which is `Any`.

You can fix this as follows:

```
def printInd (a: ArrayBuffer [Any], b: Seq[Int]) = {
    val v = a(0) match {
        case _: Double   => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [Double]]
        case _: Int      => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [Int]]
        case _: Long     => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [Long]]
        case _: String   => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [String]]
        case _  =>  a
    }
    for (i <- b) print(v(i) + " ")
}
```

or like this:

```
def printInd (a: ArrayBuffer [Any], b: Seq[Int]) = {
    val v = a(0) match {
        case _: Double   => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [Double]]
        case _: Int      => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [Int]]
        case _: Long     => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [Long]]
        case _: String   => a.asInstanceOf [ArrayBuffer [String]]
        case _  =>  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected type")
    }
    for (i <- b) print(v(i) + " ")
}
```

but in both cases, it doesn't buy you anything, because the most specific type that you can assign to `v` is still something like `ArrayBuffer[_]`. You have to do something with additional type information *inside* of the match, otherwise it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

`v` is of type `Any` according to the error message.

You need to make your `case _ => ...` return an `ArrayBuffer` as well.